# Maximal probability of an event with disjoint images

Tags: probability, measure-theory, optimization, algorithms, random-variables

During my research in measure theory I have encountered the following issue which looks like some kind of an optimization (?) problem in probability theory.

**We are given:**

$X$ a finite non-empty set

$(X,P(X),\mu)$ a probability space such that $\mu(\{x\})>0$ for each $x\in X$

$f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ two functions such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for each $x\in X$

$\mathcal{L}=\{L\in P(X)\colon\ f(x)\neq g(y)\text{ for all }x,y\in L\}$

$\alpha=\max\{\mu(L)\colon\ L\in\mathcal{L}\}$

**Question:** Is $\alpha\ge1/4$?

I have tried to answer this question designing some kind of a greedy algorithm, taking in each step such $x\in X$ for which the value $\mu\big(f^{-1}(f(x))\cap g^{-1}(g(x))\big)$ is the greatest, but I am not sure it always works, so I decided to ask here. The whole issue looks very "standard" for optimization theory, so maybe someone would know the answer immediately or at least where I should look for a hint how to solve such problems.

If there is an instance of the problem such that $\alpha<1/4$, then my question is:

**General question:** Does there exist $\beta>0$ such that $\alpha\ge\beta$ for every instance of the problem?

Comment: Where did you come up with the value of $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: I found that it works for such a scheme: for each $n>1$ let $X_n$ have $n(n-1)$ elements, let $\mu(\{x\})=1/n(n-1)$ for each $x\in X_n$, we can now allocate all possible combinations of $n$ values for $f$ and $n$ values for $g$ so that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for every $x\in X_n$. It follows that we can always find $L\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $|L|=n^2/4$, so $\mu(L)\ge1/4$. With other examples I always get that the value $1/4$ works, too.